# Will VTK 5.0.4 work on Windows 8?

Tags: cmake, tcl, data-visualization, vtk

Has anyone been able to install and configure VTK 5.0.4 with Tcl for Windows 8 ? I need version 5.0.4 because of my textbook http://www.vtk.org/VTK/help/book.html . I have Windows 8, but don't want to go through the trouble of trying to configure it with if it won't work. Has anyone done this?

Comment: I would just spend the 5 minutes work and install it and see if it works. I have used many vtk versions with windows 8.1 but not this old.

Comment: The configuration takes a lot longer, but I'll try. I can't find the 5.0.4 version online.

Comment: ***The configuration takes a lot longer*** I assumed since you tagged TCL that you would just install the binary (which will take less than 5 minutes) instead of building vtk yourself (which will take over 1 hour).

Comment: I can tell you that vtk-5.10.X works on windows 8 since I use that every day on my paid job. Although I do not use tcl and I always build vtk from source.

Comment: I downloaded VTK 5.8 and it seems to have installed, but when I go to VTK/Examples/Tutorial/Step1/TCL and double click on cone.tcl it won't run.

Comment: You probably need to install tcl also. http://www.activestate.com/activetcl?gclid=CJ73t87e38ACFcZQ7AodUFQAWw